# Attribute search in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, fields-attributes

I have added the attribute search plugin to my leaflet map, but I cannot use in the correct way. Somehow my script loads the GeoJSON features two times. The first are the styled markers, the attribute search is not working on them and when I search it says: location not found. The others are the default markers, the attribute search working fine. Can I combine the two together somehow?

You can find the example here: http://gis.xyz/ukpn_linkbox.html and you can see the code below.

```
    var ukpn_layer = new L.GeoJSON();
          function getJson(data) {
              ukpn_layer.addData(data);
          }

    var parameters2 = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters2);
    var URL2 = owsrootUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters2);


    var WFSLayer2 = null;
    var ajax2 = $.ajax({
        url : URL2,
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback : 'getJson',
        success : function (response) {
           WFSLayer2 = L.geoJson(response, {
                pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
                   var smallIcon2 = L.icon({
                                      iconSize: [27, 27],
                                      iconAnchor: [13, 27],
                                      popupAnchor:  [1, -24],
                                      iconUrl: 'leaflet/icons/' + feature.properties.csg_survey_status + '.png'
                   });

                   return L.marker(latlng, {icon: smallIcon2});
    },
                onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                    popupOptions = {maxWidth: 600};
                    layer.bindLabel('<h4>'+feature.properties.plant_no+'</h4>');
                    //sidebar.setContent('<h1>'+feature.properties.plant_no+'</h1><br>'+'<h4>'+feature.properties.csg_survey_pack+'</h4><br>'+feature.properties.csg_streetview, popupOptions);
                    layer.bindPopup('<h1>'+feature.properties.plant_no+'</h1><br>'+'<h1>'+feature.properties.csg_survey_pack+'</h4><br>'+feature.properties.csg_street_view
                        ,popupOptions);
                }
            }).addTo(ukpn_layer.addTo(map));
        }
    });



//------------------------attributom search------------------------

    var searchControl = new L.Control.Search({layer: ukpn_layer, propertyName: 'plant_no', circleLocation: true, zoom: 18});

    searchControl.on('search_locationfound', function(e) {

        e.layer.setStyle({fillColor: '#3f0', color: '#0f0'});
        if(e.layer._popup)
            e.layer.openPopup();

    }).on('search_collapsed', function(e) {

        featuresLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {   //restore feature color
            featuresLayer.resetStyle(layer);
        });
    });

    map.addControl( searchControl );  //inizialize search control
```